# Putting a background image in a CSS hexagon?

Tags: html, css

http://codepen.io/anon/pen/dqEbA

I'd like to be able to replace some of the green backgrounds with image backgrounds... is this possible with the CSS I'm using now, or do I have to an alternative CSS layout to make it possible?

Here's the CSS for reference:

```
.hex {
    float: left;
    margin-left: 3px;
    margin-bottom: -26px;
}
.hex .top {
    width: 0;
    border-bottom: 30px solid #6C6;
    border-left: 52px solid transparent;
    border-right: 52px solid transparent;
}
.hex .middle {
    width: 104px;
    height: 60px;
    background: #6C6;

}
.hex .bottom {
    width: 0;
    border-top: 30px solid #6C6;
    border-left: 52px solid transparent;
    border-right: 52px solid transparent;
}
.hex-row {
    clear: left;
}
.hex-row.even {
    margin-left: 53px;
}
```

And a snippet of the HTML:

```
<div class="hex"><div class="top"></div><div class="middle"></div><div class="bottom"</div></div>
<div class="hex"><div class="top"></div><div class="middle"></div><div class="bottom"></div></div>
```

Comment: @KheemaPandey I don't think so

Comment: Question indicate that OP have same problem.

Answer (score 0):

I guess it is, I would use `:nth-child()`. If, for instance, every third hexagon needs a background image, but they need the same picture:

```
.hex:nth-child(3n) {background-image: url('third.png');}
```

Although you can select manually the ones you need to change the background of:

```
.hex:nth-child(19) {background-image: url('bg19.png');}    
.hex:nth-child(26) {background-image: url('bg26.png');}
```

And so on.

Answer (score 0):

HTML

```
<div class="hex "><div class="bbc "></div><div class="middle abc"></div><div class="bbb "></div></div>
```

CSS

```
.hex .abc
 {
    background:red;

 }
 .bbc
 {
    border-bottom: 30px solid red;
    width: 0;
    border-left: 52px solid transparent;
    border-right: 52px solid transparent;
 }

 .bbb
 {
    width: 0;
    border-top: 30px solid red;
    border-left: 52px solid transparent;
    border-right: 52px solid transparent;
 }
```

Make these Changes and try